# Regex to match only last 3 characters when there are more

Tags: regex

With

```
(x)?xxx
```

https://regex101.com/r/MHCKZx/1

I get match xxx and xxxx with

```
test1xxxblah
test2xxxxblah
```

whereas I would like last xxx for test2xxxx

I'm really not proficient at regex I can't see what to use

Comment: Maybe you just need to add `$` at the end? `(x)?xx$`. Or `x{3}$`, `x{2,3}$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks so I updated it's not especially at the end of a line

Comment: Then `.*((x)?xxx)`, see https://regex101.com/r/MHCKZx/2 and get Group 1.

Comment: it matches test2xxxx not just xxx

Comment: It ***captures*** what you need. It does not matter what is matched.

Comment: Not sure what you want: `xxx(?!x)` maybe? or with a capture group: `x*(xxx)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ah it seems it's in group I have to learn group deeper then

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:-

```
regex --> /xxx(?=[^x])/
```

Comment: doesn't work for test2

Comment: xxx(?!x) by @JvdV works